# How to tell the current shape of my cursor?

Tags: python, windows-xp, mouse-cursor

When automating clicks and keystrokes, I often have to wait until a button finishes loading and becomes clickable. The only indicator of this is, to my knowledge, the shape of my cursor. In any programming language (preferably Python), is there any way to tell if it has changed from a pointer to a hand?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a screenshot then use the PIL imaging library combined with the current cursor position to find out how wide the mouse is. It might not work very well if there was a white or black background though.